# C# print image doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying print the bitmap with the code below but it doesn't work. I don't know why....

```
   private void btnImprimir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
        pd.Print(); 
    }

    private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Visible = false;
        button2.Visible = false;
        button3.Visible = false;
        button4.Visible = false;
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
        this.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, this.ClientRectangle);
        Point loc = new Point(this.Width, this.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, loc);
        button1.Visible = true;
        button2.Visible = true;
        button3.Visible = true;
        button4.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: 1. What do you mean with it does not work? (does it not print, does it print a empty page?)
2. Have you tried to save the bitmap to disk and view it?

Comment: I have already edited my question and deleted the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this way

```
Image bmIm;
private void PrintImage(Image img)
{
  bmIm = img;
  PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
  pd.OriginAtMargins = true;
  pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
  pd.PrintPage += pd_PrintPage;
  pd.Print();
}
void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
  double cmToUnits = 100 / 2.54;
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmIm, 0, 0,(float)(27 * cmToUnits),(float)(18 * cmToUnits));
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add the event hookup: `pd.PrintPage += pd_PrintPage;`

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I'm getting this error: The event 'System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.PrintPage' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Why pd_PrintPage is out of context?

Comment: @illDev - Did you rename your PrintPage function to pd_PrintPage?

Comment: Yees! Thx a lot..Now compile but pd.Print() getting error again...Its because theres no printer installed in this computer...thx a lot!

Comment: Yes, the code of my question works but the name of function was wrong...and this answer miss `pd.PrintPage += this.PrintPage;`

Comment: +1; @ShahroozJefri I agree; you identified a misnamed function in your comment trail.

Comment: Don't forget to remove the event handler again or it might lead to a memoryleak

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your event is not wired up properly (unless we're missing some code):

```
pd.PrintPage += this.PrintPage;
```

You were trying to assign `pd_PrintPage` which isn't in your code sample, so I don't know what it is supposed to do.

Comment: The function names matches in the OP's original question. I believe the OP modified the question in an attempt to match one of the other answers. Not sure why this answer was accepted. In the end, the OP said the issue was because "theres no printer installed in this computer" (see comments on http://stackoverflow.com/a/14319870/211627)

Comment: @Cyborgx37 yes I didn't see the full history.  Thanks.